# Get dynamically changed data from web page using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'll be as direct and as specific as possible.

I'm trying to create Greasemonkey addon that would create graph of winnings/loses on: dead link

As you can see, site has front page which dinamicly shows results of wins / loses and how much did which user win/loose. What I'm trying to do is catch every new entry so I can draw some grapsh and or statistics for user / users.

When I access div/span that should have data, it turns out to be empty. I know that reason behind this is that all divs with data relevant to me are empty on load and that they get populated later on.

What I don't know is how to access that data. I can see (using firebug console) that there are GET requests executed all the time and that in those get requests is data that I need. 
Can someone tell me or at least point me into right direction, how to access that data every time it gets refreshed / inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the $.ajaxSuccess function to specify a function in your script to be called everytime an ajax request completes in the main page. This'll be fired for *every* successful ajax request, whether it pertains to the data you're talking about or not, but should allow you to re-scrape that section of the document to grab any and all data in it after every successful request. You may want to wrap your callback function in a setTimeout of some kind to make sure their own callbacks have a chance to fire and inject/modify the content before you scrape it. It should still seem instantaneous to the user if you set a timeout of, say, 1-10ms.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I just created small simple script: $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
alert("test");
});
Nothing happens and i can see site updating it's data all the time.

Comment: Hm...ok...now i dn tknow what happened or how it happened, but simply waiting for like 5 seconds before simply accessing data just returned data it had to return. I have no idea how it didint work for few hours now.